# How can type a query to PostgresSQL that includes quotes, by using pg's Pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, express

I’m building an API with Nodejs, Express, and PostgreSQL

I’m also using the pg’s Pool for querying the database

I want to make a query that includes LIKE, as in SELECT * FROM database WHERE field LIKE ‘%string%’, (the documentation says that it has to include the quotes)

The problem is that when writing the query, I type:

```
pool.query(“SELECT * FROM database WHERE field LIKE ‘%$1%’”, [ str ], (…) => {
   …
});
```

pool.query should replace $1 with str, but instead, I receive the error: column "%$1%" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The entire value on the right hand side of the `LIKE` keyword is a single string, so you have to use a placeholder for the entire thing. With the pg client you're using that looks like:

```
pool.query(“SELECT * FROM database WHERE field LIKE $1", [ "%" + str + "%" ], (…) => {
   …
});
```

You can also use https://www.atdatabases.org, which lets you inline the placeholder while still escaping it properly. That would look like:

```
await db.query(sql`
  SELECT * FROM database WHERE field LIKE ${`%${str}%`}
`)
```